# Mostrar un resultado después de una consulta SQL

Tags: php, sql

Necesito obtener el valor de un campo en mi base de datos a través de una consulta `sql`

El campo que necesito obtener está dentro de la columna `claveVerify` y donde `email` coincida con `$email`

Lo he hecho de la siguiente forma, pero no me funciona y también, lo veo un poco absurdo en la manera de intentar obtenerlo

```html
  $checkCode = "SELECT claveVerify FROM empresa WHERE email = '$email";
  $result = $conn->query($checkCode);
  $rows = $result->fetchAll();
  
 
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
  
   $verifyCode = $row['claveVerify']; 
    
}
```

Comment: mencionas que no te funciona, podrías agregar que es lo que te esta devolviendo?

Comment: Lo que me falla es $rows = $result->fetchAll(); pues después de esta linea el resto de código (html php...etc) deja de funcionar

Comment: Te falta cerrar las comillas despues de `'$email`

Comment: Odio estos fallos tan tontos..... GRACIAS

Comment: deberías usar solo fetch, por que solo regresas una fila y no requeririas un foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta cerrar comillas simples en $email

```html
  $checkCode = "SELECT claveVerify FROM empresa WHERE email = '$email'";
  $result = $conn->query($checkCode);
  $rows = $result->fetchAll();
  
 
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
  
   $verifyCode = $row['claveVerify']; 
    
}
```